# The `this` keyword is not helpful when using to perform sum operation on an object property

Tags: javascript, object

I came across this interesting and weird issue when playing around with a simple object.The type of both the numbers declared as properties of the object `obj` are numbers as output in the Chrome dev console. The `this` should have referred to the current object.However, when trying to calculate the sum , the result is `NaN` instead of the sum. Interestingly, using the object to directly reference the numbers works when calculating the sum.

```
var obj={
number1: 2, 
number2: 3,
sum : this.number1 + this.number2
};
obj.sum;

NaN
```

BUT the following code works

```
var obj={
number1: 2, 
number2: 3,
sum : obj.number1 + obj.number2
};
obj.sum;

5
```

Comment: Just do the later, then. Don't use this. Simple!

Comment: "*The `this` should have referred to the current object.*" [No, it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) it references *the current context* and that will depend on how the code you are running has been executed. If it's inside a function it *might* be the context of the function but that can be changed with stuff like `.call` or `.apply`.